# Boolean-and all incoming pipeline objects in powershell

Tags: powershell

What is the most convenient way to 'and' together a pipeline, such that the returned value is true iff every incoming object evaluated to true? Such as:

`$fileList | % { Test-Path $_ } | Boolean-And`

The above snippet should be testing that every file in fileList exists. But there is no 'Boolean-And' function. Is there a different name/way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
@($fileList | % { Test-Path $_ }) -notcontains $false
```

As a pipeline function:

```
function And-Boolean
 { $input -notcontains $false }
```